# flutter DropDownButton remove arrow icon?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have a simple DropDownButton and would like to disable/hide the downward pointing arrow that is attached to it but there doesn't seem to be an option for it?

A very hacky workaround is to set a custom icon and give it a transparent color but that really does not feel like a good solution.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Make use of the Visibility widget like this -

```
icon: Visibility (visible:false, child: Icon(Icons.arrow_downward)),
```

See the complete code below:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(const MyApp());

/// This is the main application widget.
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  static const String _title = 'Flutter Code Sample';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: _title,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(title: const Text(_title)),
        body: const Center(
          child: MyStatefulWidget(),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

/// This is the stateful widget that the main application instantiates.
class MyStatefulWidget extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyStatefulWidget({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyStatefulWidget> createState() => _MyStatefulWidgetState();
}

/// This is the private State class that goes with MyStatefulWidget.
class _MyStatefulWidgetState extends State<MyStatefulWidget> {
  String dropdownValue = 'One';

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DropdownButton<String>(
      value: dropdownValue,
      icon: Visibility (visible:false, child: Icon(Icons.arrow_downward)),
      iconSize: 24,
      elevation: 16,
      style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.deepPurple),
      underline: Container(
        height: 2,
        color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
      ),
      onChanged: (String? newValue) {
        setState(() {
          dropdownValue = newValue!;
        });
      },
      items: <String>['One', 'Two', 'Free', 'Four']
          .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
        return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
          value: value,
          child: Text(value),
        );
      }).toList(),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank, works well! I actually found another solution along the way: Setting iconSize to 0 in the DropDownButton achieves the same thing.

Comment: The Visibility() widget is very useful in cases when you might wanna conditionally show a widget (a text, icon, container, anything), because the visible property will accept any expression that evaluates to a boolean.

Answer (score 28):

add `iconSize: 0.0` to your `DropdownButton` like this

```
DropdownButton(
  iconSize: 0.0,
  ...
)
```

Comment: This doesn't work. You just get a really small arrow.

Answer (score 9):

The best way is to defined an empty Widget as icon.

An empty Widget can be set with `SizedBox.shrink()`, so you need to add `icon: SizedBox.shrink(),` to your DropdownButton parameters.

Here a quick example :

```
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DropdownButton<String>(
      value: dropdownValue,
      elevation: 16,
      icon: SizedBox.shrink(),
      style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.deepPurple),
      underline: Container(
        height: 2,
        color: Colors.deepPurpleAccent,
      ),
      onChanged: (String? newValue) {
        setState(() {
          dropdownValue = newValue!;
        });
      },
      items: <String>['One', 'Two', 'Free', 'Four']
          .map<DropdownMenuItem<String>>((String value) {
        return DropdownMenuItem<String>(
          value: value,
          child: Text(value),
        );
      }).toList(),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```dart
  DropdownSearch<SpeakerAndAuthorModel>(
      dropdownButtonProps: const DropdownButtonProps(isVisible: false ),
  );
```