Flutter removing dropdown menu's trailing icon with clickable area
I want to completely remove dropdown menu's trailing icon. I added below code to remove it.
 DropdownMenu<ColorLabel>(
   trailingIcon: SizedBox.shrink(),
   selectedTrailingIcon: SizedBox.shrink(),
   initialSelection: ColorLabel.green,
   controller: colorController,

However the clickable area (or whatever the name is) is still appears. Is it possible to remove completely?
TIA

Does this answer to your question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67997808/5882307 ?

Well not exactly. The clickable region appears even with Visibility widget method.

I think you should create a Flutter Github issue
